# Value of variable keeps reverting back to null JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working with this following code in order to make a simple password generator. The issue I am facing is that when the passwordLength function is run, and no answer is given, it goes through the given process, including alerting me: "Incorrect value. Please choose a number between 8 and 128." Following that prompt the function is re-run. However, when I re-enter my value(this time with a correct value). It goes through to the "return lengthInput", but doesn't return the value I just input. It returns the value that was generated in the first loop. In this case, that would be null. How do I get it to return the value I just typed in rather than sending the value that was previously run through the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always create an SO snippet to present your actual problem. In your case you forgot to store the returned value of the recursion call in the variable `lengthInput`:

```js
const passwordLength = function() {
  var lengthInput = window.prompt("How long do you want your password to be? Please choose a number between 8 and 128.");

  if (lengthInput < 8 || lengthInput > 128) { 
    window.alert("Incorrect value. Please choose a number between 8 and 128.");
    lengthInput=passwordLength();
  }

  return lengthInput;
};

console.log(passwordLength())
```

The code in this snippet is still overcomplicated, as it will unnecessarily go into a recursion. But at least it will use the latest "legal" value for `lengthInput`.

A simpler solution to your problem might be:

```js
const passwordLength = function() {
  var lengthInput;
  while ((lengthInput = window.prompt("How long do you want your password to be? Please choose a number between 8 and 128.")), lengthInput < 8 || lengthInput > 128)
    window.alert("Incorrect value. Please choose a number between 8 and 128.");
  return lengthInput;
};

console.log(passwordLength())
```

Or even:

```js
const passwordLength = function() {
  do var lengthInput = window.prompt("How long do you want your password to be? Please choose a number between 8 and 128.");
  while (lengthInput < 8 || lengthInput > 128)
  return lengthInput;
};

console.log(passwordLength())
```